# Compare few object and check are have same value

Tags: c#

I would like to know if the lens does not repeat or the user did not give the same values.

It is my Ticket class :

```
   public class TicketBl
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int CinemaId { get; set; }
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public int CinemaHallId { get; set; }
        public string Row { get; set; }
        public int Seat { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfSeance { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have list of tickets :

```
var tickets = new List<TicketBl>
            {
                new TicketBl()
                {
                    CinemaHallId = 1, MovieId = 1, Row = "A", Seat = 1, CinemaId = 1,
                    TimeOfSeance = new DateTime(2019, 05, 06), UserEmail = "bk@gmail.com"
                },
                new TicketBl()
                {
                    CinemaHallId = 1, MovieId = 1, Row = "A", Seat = 2, CinemaId = 1,
                    TimeOfSeance = new DateTime(2019, 05, 06), UserEmail = "bk@gmail.com@gmail.com"
                },
                new TicketBl()
                {
                    CinemaHallId = 1, MovieId = 1, Row = "A", Seat = 1, CinemaId = 1,
                    TimeOfSeance = new DateTime(2019, 05, 06), UserEmail = "bk@gmail.com@gmail.com"
                }
            };
```

I created some value comparer class but it's not working. Equals isn't good for comparer values ?? How to check the values in object is the same.

```
public static class ValuesComparer
    {
        public static bool CheckListHasSameValues<T>(List<T> values)
        {
if (values.Count() == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < values.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (values[i].Equals(values[j]))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The word "lens" only appears once, so it's not clear what that means. A first step is to figure out, in this context, which duplicate values you want to look at. Do you want to know if there's another `TicketB1` with *exactly* the same properties, or are there just certain properties of the class that you want to consider? There are a few ways to accomplish this but it depends on those details.

Answer (score 0):

Compare will not compare items of different type like strings and integers.  Use IEqual :

```
    public class Ticket : IEquatable<Ticket>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int CinemaId { get; set; }
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public int CinemaHallId { get; set; }
        public string Row { get; set; }
        public int Seat { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfSeance { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public Boolean Equals(Ticket other)
        {
            return
                (this.Id == other.Id) &&
                (this.CinemaId == other.CinemaId) &&
                (this.MovieId == other.MovieId) &&
                (this.CinemaHallId == other.CinemaHallId) &&
                (this.Row == other.Row) &&
                (this.Seat == other.Seat) &&
                (this.TimeOfSeance == other.TimeOfSeance);

        }
    }
```